# Periodocity of $a^{pn+q}$ mod $m$

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

Is $a^{pn+q}$ mod $m$ periodic? $a$, $p$ and $q$ are constants. $n$ is varied here.
If it is periodic then how can I find the periodicity efficiently?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a function of what here? Is $a$ fixed and you want to know if this quantity is periodic as a function of $n$, or is it $a$ that's varying?

Comment: @David Loeffler, n is varied. a, p, q are constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has the same character of periodicity as $A \cdot P^n \pmod m$ where the constant parts of your function are renamed (and evaluated $\pmod m$ before) as $A=a^q $ and $P= a^p$ because you can write $a^q \cdot (a^p)^n \pmod m$

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please explain how I can get the periodicity of $AP^{n}(mod m)$ efficiently?

Comment: About the fact of periodicity we have the "little Fermat". About the details - usually only by doing it explicitely for the first turn along increasing $n$. However, if $m$ is a prime, then we know that the length of the period for increasing $n$ is at most $m-1$ and can even be a divisor of that quantity. Besides of that i've no idea about a (more) efficient way than explicitely determining it for one period.